# Why can not connect JConsole?

Tags: java, windows, monitoring, jconsole

I have used java 18.0.2.1.However, I can not local connect Jconsole.I keep getting the message "Connection Lost: Reconnect ?". [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HNCD.jpg)

When I tried to run it again on two different computers, it worked on one and can not work on the other. I used same version and same configuration and I have controlled file permission on windows OS. Also, jconsole doesn't show its own graphs either and gives the same warning "Connection Lost: Reconnect ?". Why could this be caused?